# Groovy: got StackOverflowError by invokeMethod within Interceptor

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

A class named `InterceptorTest` implementing `GroovyInterceptable`,which could be an interceptor,has its `invokeMethod` overrided as follows:

```
class InterceptorTest implements GroovyInterceptable{
    def invokeMethod(String name,args){
        println "intercepting call! " //println a short message
    }
}
```

I thought class `InterceptorTest` to be an interceptor would delegate all method calls to `invokeMethod`,so the following should work:

```
def interceptor=new InterceptorTest()
println interceptor.work()
```

Unfortunately, I got a StackOverflowError，seemingly at the body of `invokeMethod`,but I had no clue why it happened.

As a counterpart, I altered the function body,not `println` but just `return` message:

```
class InterceptorTest implements GroovyInterceptable{
    def invokeMethod(String name,args){
        "intercepting call! " //return a short message
    }
}
```

then it worked fine:

```
def interceptor=new InterceptorTest()
println interceptor.work()  //get "intercepting call!"
```

But WHY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_groovyinterceptable), "println" is actually a method in the class, injected by Groovy. Therefore, you achieve infinite recursion by trying to call it within the invokeMethod function.

> We cannot use default groovy methods like **println** because these methods are injected into all Groovy objects so they will be intercepted too.